# Direction mismatch and does not have driver warning in Vivado

Tags: vhdl, warnings

Hi I am getting these warnings and because of these warnings my code does not work as intented. To be specific here are the complete warnings below. By the way, since these 2 warnings are closely related to each other, I asked this question including both these warnings instead of asking 2 seperate questions.

```
[Synth 8-547] port direction mismatch for port 'douta' 
[Synth 8-3848] Net data_out_ram in module/entity top_mod does not have 
driver.
```

However, there are no need for these warnings. As far as I know driver means connection and this signal below has connections. I mean I do not understand the reason behind these warnings.

```
signal data_out_ram : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0); --declared in top_module

U4: Block_Ram port map(addra => address_ram,
                       clka => clk,
                       dina => data_in_ram,
                       douta => data_out_ram, -- here
                       wea => write_enable);

U5: Brightness_Contrast port map(clk_in => clk,
                                 operation => operation,
                                 pos_x => pos_x,
                                 pos_y => pos_y,
                                 data_in => data_out_ram, --here
                                 cursor_pos_x => cursor_pos_x,
                                 cursor_pos_y => cursor_pos_y,
                                 length => length,
                                 output_of_operation => output_of_operation,
                                 mode => mode);

U6: Display port map(clk_in => clk,
                     rst => rst,
                     visible => visible,
                     data_r => data_r,
                     data_g => data_g,
                     data_b => data_b,
                     pos_x => pos_x,
                     pos_y => pos_y,
                     data_out_ram => data_out_ram, --here
                     length => length,
                     cursor_pos_x => cursor_pos_x,
                     cursor_pos_y => cursor_pos_y);

component Display
port(clk_in : in  std_logic ;
rst     : in  std_logic;
visible: in std_logic;
data_r  : out std_logic_vector(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0);
data_g  : out std_logic_vector(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0);
data_b  : out std_logic_vector(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0);
pos_x  : in integer range 0 to 2047;
pos_y  : in integer range 0 to 2047;
display_data: in std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
length: in integer range 0 to PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT;
cursor_pos_x: in integer range 0 to PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT;
cursor_pos_y: in integer range 0 to PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT
);
end component;

component Block_Ram
port(addra :in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
 clka : in std_logic;
 dina : in std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
 douta: in std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
 wea: in std_logic);
 end component;

component Brightness_Contrast
port (
clk_in : in  std_logic;
operation : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
pos_x: in integer range 0 to 2047 ;  
pos_y: in integer range 0 to 2047 ; 
data_in: in std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
cursor_pos_x: in integer range 0 to PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT;
cursor_pos_y: in integer range 0 to PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT;
length: in integer range 0 to PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT;
output_of_operation: out std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
mode: in std_logic
);
```

Ram is constructed with block memory generator

I really need help on this. How can I solve the issue here??

Comment: How do you expect us to answer with incomplete code? It is probably, exactly as the error message says, a port direction mismatch but you haven't included any of the port declarations!

Comment: I am sorry Mr Drummond, I added what is required. I truly understand the message but do not know what to do since nothing seems wrong to my eye.

Comment: `data_out_ram` is not on the component declaration of `display`. Your code is inconsistent. And if you're trying to connect `display_data`, `douta` and `data_in`. All are input ports. cannot connect input ports together without a driver (output port).

Comment: Aaand there it is. You are connecting two `in` ports together. One of them should probably be an `out` port; that will also supply the missing driver.

Comment: douta is output

Comment: What are exactly input ports you mentioned Mr Drummond??

Comment: `component Block_Ram port([...]douta:` **in** `std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);` <-- no, it's not

Comment: `douta: in std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);` and you think it's an output?

Comment: As I said douta is output of ram.Its name implies that other things are intput(data in and display data).In display port map I made things correct.I made put display data in left hand side in display port map.

Comment: so what is output of Ram if I am wrong Mr Drummond? How can both dina and douta be inputs?

Comment: `douta: in std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);` why is your Block_Ram `douta` port mode **in** for your component declaration?  (Note there are no mode **out** ports present on the component declaration). During elaboration the component and entity declarations would be required to match. (IEEE Std 1076-2008, 7.3.3 Default binding indication, paras 6 and 7). You don't show the entity declaration for Block_Ram nor a configuration specification with an entity aspect. There appears to be no driver present on the elaborated net `data_out_ram`. Every other connection is to a mode **in** port.

Comment: Runo, somehow you are missing @BrianDrummond’s point. Look at your “component Block_Ram port(...)”. Do you see any “out” signals?

Comment: @runo: it is like you don't want your question to be answered. It doesn't work because you made a mistake. We point you to the mistake. You should accept that, or not ask a question here.

Comment: I apologize to everyone who helped. You are right I made a mistake that I could not even notice. I could not feel more stupid than this moment. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay.

Beyond the obviously incorrect port mode on `douta: in std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);` there is a lesson to be learned here.

VHDL was designed in a very different era, when computers were much less powerful and compilation was a fairly slow and expensive operation; therefore it allowed modules to be separately compiled and checked, without having to read and compile a huge number of other modules.

The `Component` statement is a part of this mechanism : it tells the compiler your design intent is to connect this module to a `component Block_Ram` with a bunch of input ports and no outputs, namely a [Write Only Memory](http://www.sigwom.com/?page_id=17).

It faithfully complies with this design intent, alerting you to any problems along the way; such as these error messages : a signal with no driver. You can resolve the error any way you want, perhaps by adding a driver `data_out_ram <= something_else;` eliminating that error.

Later on, the design will be "elaborated", joining a bunch of successfully compiled modules together, searching the appropriate libraries for a Write Only Memory matching the component declaration. But at this stage, you can compile without having written any of those modules.

If it finds one, all is well, and your design will synthesise, successfully implementing your design intent as stated.

However, more likely, elaboration will fail because the closest match in your libraries is something like

```
entity Block_Ram
port(addra :in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
 clka : in std_logic;
 dina : in std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
 douta: out std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
 wea: in std_logic);
end entity;
```

a perfectly normal RAM, with an `out` port for `douta` where your `in` port should be. Apparently your compiler is performing that check at compilation instead of elaboration, to give you the "port direction mismatch" error. And why not? Compilation is orders of magnitude faster than it was in the 1980s.

---

The truly sad thing is that VHDL is still taught as though it should be used for 1980s designs compiled on 1980s machines.

That degree of separate compilation is completely unnecessary now.

So DELETE ALL your component declarations, and use direct entity instantiation instead. That is:

```
U4: entity Work.Block_Ram port map(addra => address_ram,
                       clka => clk,
                       dina => data_in_ram,
                       douta => data_out_ram, 
                       wea => write_enable);
```

and it will directly instantiate whatever `BlockRam` you have already compiled into library `Work`. (This DOES require that all those entities have already been written, of course, and it will compile them to cross-check the port interfaces). And if `BlockRam` is in some other library, simply change the library name in the instantiation.

In the likely event that you really wanted a RAM with an actual output port, this would have sailed through without errors, because there was no `Component` declaration to make a silly mistake in.

This is one of several areas where VHDL teaching lags decades behind good VHDL practice, encouraging large and error-prone designs where smaller, simpler forms would reduce mistakes.

Comment: Thanks Mr Drummond I took my lesson and now acquired more knowledge on this thanks to you.